# Can't use jQuery to change select value to option dynamically populated by ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, html-select

Changing the value of a select option just like this, http://jsfiddle.net/ueDTd/, doesn't work if the options are populated by AJAX.

This is supposed to change the option back to what it was after the page reloads because the form is found invalid (missing required fields, etc)

The result is that it always changes to the first dynamically populated result which also happens to have a value of "1".

Here is the code in its entirety including the AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

var dh_json;
var url = base_url+'doc_headings/get_json_doc_headings';
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(encoded_json){
            dh_json = encoded_json;
            $.each(encoded_json, function(key, index) {
                $('#doc_headings').append(
                    $('<option>', { value : index.id } )
                    .text(index.content)
                );
            }); 
        } // End of success function of ajax form
}); // End of ajax call    

$('#doc_headings').change(function() {
   var dh_el_value = $('#doc_headings').val();
  $.each(dh_json, function(key, index) {
    if (index.id == dh_el_value) {
        $('#body').attr("placeholder", index.directions);
    }
  });
});

$('select#doc_headings').val(doc_headings_selected);
```

});

and here is the HTML for the select element:

```
        <select id="doc_headings" name="doc_headings">
        <option disabled="disabled" value="no" selected="selected"> - Document Type - </option>
    </select>
```

How can I change the value of a select field with ajax-generated options?

Comment: It's asyncronous, so the options are appended after the function that sets the value at the end of your script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening:

1. Sending out the AJAX request
2. You then move into the execution of "$('select#doc_headings').val(doc_headings_selected);"
3. Receive response back from the server, firing the *success function* in the ajax call...which is populating the select menu.

Move your last line of code (listed below) to the end of the success function in your ajax call, and it should work.

```
$('select#doc_headings').val(doc_headings_selected);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I thought of this... I don't know why I didn't just try it! Too busy making futile attempts, I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

use `on` like

```
$('#doc_headings').on('change',function() {
 var dh_el_value = $('#doc_headings').val();
$.each(dh_json, function(key, index) {
if (index.id == dh_el_value) {
    $('#body').attr("placeholder", index.directions);
}
 });
});
```